# how do i split my result using json

Tags: php, json

im using a text messaging service provider to send and receive messages. the following is the code that works successfully to retrieve messages from the texting server and displays on my website

the problem is when it displays this data its in one big chunk,sorry im not a great programmer therfore I want to split each text messages up by a few spaces,

please could you help me write up a json script that would allow me to split up my result, cheers

Answer (score 2):

You need to decode the JSON from the string into an array or object, using [json_decode()](https://www.php.net/json_decode) it has a second parameter that's bool (When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.)

So something *like* (Object):

```
$responseObj = json_decode($response);
foreach ( $responseObj as $key => $value )
    echo "$key = $value<br>";
```

So something *like* (Array):

```
$responseArray = json_decode($response, true);
foreach ( $responseArray as $key => $value )
    echo "$key = $value<br>";
```

Comment: @Loz Cherone: thanks for "enhancing". But that's a kind of do-my-homework-please-question, and thus I limited to the min.

Comment: thanks guys, but this script dosnt show any messages :S juts the first section before the messages

Comment: Yes. probably the array/object reference needs to adjusted according to the current actual JSON string. That's why I emphasized "_like_ ..."

Answer (score 1):

first of all do use `json_decode` function of php then it will come up in an `array where at "messages" index` you can find your all messages. After that you have to run for each loop then you can get your code working.

```
$arr = json_decode($response, true);

foreach($arr['messages'] as $message){
 echo $message['message'];
}
```

Comment: hey ravi I worked with your code does what I wanted :) I added the br init: $arr = json_decode($response, true);

 foreach($arr['messages'] as $message){
  echo $message['message']."<br/><br/>" ;
}

Comment: that works great but I also want the date to appear mind if you could add the date section, I tried but getting error at line, thanks

Comment: just do below thing : $arr = json_decode($response, true);

foreach($arr['messages'] as $message){
 echo $message['message']."<br /><br />";echo $message['date']."<br /><br />";
}

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $response = json_decode($response);
    foreach($response['messages'] as $msgObj) {
        print $msgObj->message . "<br/><br/>";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Poor answer, so just copy and paste and this should work for the OP, dont need json_decode no?

Comment: `$response` is a string, what should `$response['messages']` give? Aside: the key is `message` and not `messages`...

Comment: @AxelAmthor the index is messages at one place and message at other place. whats wrong with solution after using json_decode?